# Cloning Drives (beginner wanting to learn)

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, partitioning, external-hard-drive, clone

To start off I'm newish to working on computers but i'm excited to learn more about it

I recently was given 2 laptops by my parents so i took parts out to upgrade my current laptop.(there's had missing keys, screen wouldnt turn on, etc) 
so one of the laptops i was given has a much larger hard drive in it(a 320 GB Seagate HDD) and i reformatted it, removed the partitions on it (except a 16 GB Healthy Recovery Partition that i cannot remove) I want to clone my current hard drive into it which leads me to a problem.

I've looked into videos on how to use macrium, I've watched numerous tutorial videos on how to safely clone my hard drive. but I have been unable to get an answer on how the healthy safety partition will effect cloning(the 16 gig one that I want to upgrade to)

1. is it safe to clone my current hard drive to it with this safety partition?
2. why can't i get rid of that final partition(i reformatted the hard drive fixed the un alocated space i just dont want this to cause any damage).
3. I'm using macrium free for my cloning process with the information i provided will i be safe to do so?(running windows 10 pro)

please any help to a newbie is appreciated!

Comment: Drive cloning will overwrite any partition on the target drive. If you never want to recover the OS on the target drive, then you don't need to worry about losing it. If you try to copy partitions individually, you will need to rebuild the partition table, whereas drive cloning will include the partition table from the source drive. I have never come across Macrium, so I have no idea if it will handle partition moving and resizing when the target is a different size, or whether it's something you will need to do afterwards to use the larger space.

Answer (score 0):

Your better off booting the computer with Clonezilla, and using it to image the drives.  If the source drive is smaller than the target drive.

Clonezilla will wipe away all partition.  Also gparted can delete all partitions.

In Windows: (administrative command prompt)

1. diskpart
2. select disk 0  (better make sure your doing the right drive cause it will all been **gone** in a second.
3. clean
4. exit

all partition gone.